# Is there such a thing as password auto-fill for thick client/native desktop applications?

Tags: passwords, single-sign-on

If I have desktop non-browser based applications that require a username and password is there any software I can install on my machine that will fill in those credentials for me please? Ideally centrally managed so that the passwords can revoked from the installed wallet/vault.

Comment: Try searching for password managers. Keepas for example

Comment: That's pretty interesting thanks - is there anything that takes it a stage further though and will recognise which application is being opened and auto-fill I wonder?

Comment: Maybe a "portal" with icons for all the thick client apps so that it's certain which I'm opening and so that if someone else uses the machine, their creds can be used based on the fact the logged into the "portal"